# Too slow face recognition via dlib

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

I am using this OpenCV exapmle [for face detection](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.0/samples/dnn/resnet_ssd_face.cpp). And then I am using [this dlib example](http://dlib.net/dnn_face_recognition_ex.cpp.html) for face recognition. First step is to detect face with OpenCV and save detected rectangular in jpg. Also I do the same for the second image. After that I load this faces to dlib model and it tries to recognize if there the same person. Everything is working and even correct but it takes about 1 min 30 sec on my i7 8550U and 16gb ram to recognize faces. So to my mind I am doing smth wrong.  There is some code how I try to compare faces:

```
anet_type dlibNet;
deserialize("dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat") >> dlibNet;
...
cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("img1.jpg");
cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread("img2.jpg");
cv::resize(img1, img1, cv::Size(150, 150));
cv::resize(img2, img2, cv::Size(150, 150));

cv_image<bgr_pixel> image1(img1);
matrix<rgb_pixel> matr1;
assign_image(matr1, image1);

cv_image<bgr_pixel> image2(img2);
matrix<rgb_pixel> matr2;
assign_image(matr2, image2);

std::vector<matrix<rgb_pixel>> faces;
faces.push_back(matr1);
faces.push_back(matr2);
std::vector<matrix<float, 0, 1>> face_descriptors = dlibNet(faces);
if (length(face_descriptors[0] - face_descriptors[1]) < 0.6)
        cout << "Same person" << endl;
else
        cout << "Fail. Different people" << endl;
```

Comment: And you built your program with what compiler options?  Giving us timings means nothing if you are running an unoptimized build.

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't thought about that. I have replaced debug library version with release version and now it take about 1.5 sec to recognize, thanks